# Unable to get the JSONP from url with android volley

Tags: android, json

I'm used with getting json data via volley in android but today, I came across the problem that I cannot solve. There is a api I wanted to use that returns a JSONP and not a simple json. Is it possible to retrieve the JSONP data in some way in android ?

```
 String url =
                "https://getbible.net/json?passage=1Jn3:16";

        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        mQueue.add(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("TAGGED",response.toString());
                    }
                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                }));
```

Answer (score 0):

its because your API returns invalid JSON format

```
({
    "book": [
        {
            "book_ref": "1 Jhn",
            "book_name": "1 John",
            "book_nr": "62",
            "chapter_nr": "3",
            "chapter": {
                "16": {
                    "verse_nr": "16",
                    "verse": "Hereby perceive we the love of God, because he laid down his life for us: and we ought to lay down our lives for the brethren."
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "direction": "LTR",
    "type": "verse",
    "version": "kjv"
});
```

its adding this bracket `(` at starting and at end this `);` so by correcting this it should work!

so your corrected response should be like this as its JSON format

```
{
    "book": [
        {
            "book_ref": "1 Jhn",
            "book_name": "1 John",
            "book_nr": "62",
            "chapter_nr": "3",
            "chapter": {
                "16": {
                    "verse_nr": "16",
                    "verse": "Hereby perceive we the love of God, because he laid down his life for us: and we ought to lay down our lives for the brethren."
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "direction": "LTR",
    "type": "verse",
    "version": "kjv"
}
```

Comment: Thank you , But the problem is it's not my api.

Comment: ok then probably you can remove starting first index, second last index and last index of this string, after that can use this JSON data., and You can report this issue to the owner of this API. :)

Comment: It's invalid JSON because it's not JSON: it's JSONP. Small, but significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try change you method Request.Method.GET instead of Request.Method.POST